# mod_rewrite rules definition

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite

i have a Problem with my .htaccess/mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sometest/(.+)/page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?main=sometest/$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?main=$1 [QSA]
```

This does not work. If i visit my website the css files are not included.
I include them like "/assets/css/blabla.css".

If i delete just one RewriteRule (doesn't matter which one) it works. But i need both rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use skip flag `skip|S=num`for this.

like :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/([^/]+)\.([^/]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^ - [S=2,L]
RewriteRule ^sometest/(.+)/page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?main=sometest/$1&page=$2 [S=1,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?main=$1 [QSA,L]
```

see this page for more information http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Hi,
i tried it, but he can't load my css files, even with the skip flag.
You have another idea? Thanks, Marcel

Comment: Hi again, now i get the following error: 

Not Found

The requested URL /sometest/all/page/2 was not found on this server.

Comment: now i have the problem with my css files again. the html code is "<link href="/assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">" but rewrite executes "index.php?main=assets/css/custom.css"

Comment: hum, now i took a look in the apache2 error log:
[Wed Apr 10 00:15:31 2013] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-d' is not supported and will be ignored.

[Wed Apr 10 00:15:31 2013] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.

but if i remove the NC, it doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: it must work maybe in your Apache version is not support see  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond find `'-d'` explain more about it